# Why is the bash file not found when deploying to K8s?

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

I have a dockerfile with a custom SQL server 2019 installation running a bashscript, which in turn calls another bash script:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU8-ubuntu-16.04 
ARG BuildConfiguration=Debug

USER root
# Install Unzip
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install unzip -y

# Install SQLPackage for Linux and make it executable
RUN wget -progress=bar:force -q -O sqlpackage.zip https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2143497 \
    && unzip -qq sqlpackage.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage \
    && chmod +x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage

USER mssql

# Create a config directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/config
WORKDIR /usr/config

# Copy required source files
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/config
COPY configure-db.sh /usr/config
COPY setup.sql /usr/config
COPY PrepareServer.sql /usr/config
COPY tSQLt.class.sql /usr/config
# Copy the dacpac, that we will be deploying. Make sure the project has built before you run the dockerfile!
COPY ./bin/${BuildConfiguration}/Database.dacpac /usr/config

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["tail -f /dev/null"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=15s CMD /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -Q "select 1" && grep -q "MSSQL CONFIG COMPLETE" ./config.log
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &

/bin/bash /usr/config/configure-db.sh

eval $1
```

configure-db.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait for MSSQL server to start
export STATUS=1
i=0

while [[ $STATUS -ne 0 ]] && [[ $i -lt 30 ]]; do
    i=$i+1
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -t 1 -U sa -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -Q "select 1" >> /dev/null
    STATUS=$?
done

if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then 
    echo "Error: MSSQL SERVER took more than thirty seconds to start up."
    exit 1
fi

echo "======= MSSQL SERVER STARTED ========"
# Run the setup script to create the DB and the schema in the DB
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -d master -i setup.sql
#install the tSQLt CLR for testing
echo "======= PREPARING FOR tSQLt ========"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -d master -i PrepareServer.sql
echo "======= PREPARATION FOR tSQLt FINISHED ========"
echo "======= INSTALLING tSQLt ========"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -d master -i tSQLt.class.sql
echo "======= INSTALLING tSQLt FINISHED========"

echo "======= Starting Deployment of Dacpac ========"
/opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /a:Publish /tsn:. /tdn:${MSSQL_DB} /tu:sa /tp:$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD /sf:/usr/config/Database.dacpac

echo "======= Finished Deployment of Dacpac ========"
echo "======= MSSQL CONFIG COMPLETE ======="
```

This is then deployed to Kuberenetes, but upon startup I see the following lines in the log:

```
./entrypoint.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./entrypoint.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./entrypoint.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
: No such file or directoryigure-db.sh
./entrypoint.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
```

I have searched for the carriage return in Notepad++ and VSC, but could not find any. Notepad, as well as VSC display, that the EOL is set to Unix (LF)

I have tried to manually run the file configure-db.sh with bash inside the pod and receive the following output:

```
mssql@sql-dev:/usr/config$ /bin/bash configure-db.sh 
configure-db.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
configure-db.sh: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Weirdly enough, running this with docker-compose works flawlessly. Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

**Update**
Just to make sure, I did not overlook anything by accident I went ahead, and opened up the solution folder on WSL / Ubuntu and created an entrypoint2.sh with `sudo chown +x ./entrypoint2.sh` and referenced this in the dockerfile. I made sure, that the line ending were indeed LF / `\n` and *not* CR-LF, then checked the file in and deployed it. In addition I run the file through `dos2unix` again.

The outcome is identical. It works using docker-compose, but throws an error using Kubernetes:

```
./entrypoint2.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./entrypoint2.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
./entrypoint2.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
: No such file or directoryusr/config/configure-db.sh
./entrypoint2.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't that bash isn't found, it's that `\r` isn't found. This indicates you've saved your script with Windows linefeeds and tried to run that script on a Linux platform. From your editor, save the script with Linux linefeeds (LF, not CR-LF). Or you can use a tool like dos2unix to strip the carriage returns from the script.

Comment: As already stated, I have already tried that, but I simply could not find a carriage in return in either file. Dos2unix applies zero changes to both files

Comment: @Marco have you been looking at the file that is *inside* the image?

Comment: Right now I can't even start up a pod. Getting even more errors of type \r is not a command, after trying something out. Seems like they really are stuck inside the image and I can't figure out why. 
`tail: cannot open '/dev/null'$'\r' for reading: No such file or directory`. Again ... coming up fine locally in docker-compose

Comment: @Marco pull the image that is being deployed in k8s, don't debug the one you have built locally if it's not where the problem is occurring. And run it with a different entrypoint, there's a `--entrypoint` flag you can use to change it to a shell.

Comment: You are right, running `docker run -it -u root --entrypoint /bin/bash localhost:32000/sql:253` reveals that fixing the files with dos2unix makes the scripts work again. Unfortunately, that does not help me at this point, because all scripts I create will be flawed at this point.

Comment: For further troubleshooting you may open those files in `vim` within the Linux container and use `:set list` to display whitespace characters. You may also use `cat -A` or `cat -e`. Anyway, it looks like you will need to edit all your scripts and convert them to the proper format, then re-build the image.

Comment: Another place I've seen generate the issue is git itself, when configured to automatically convert line endings for Windows when checking out the files.

Comment: git on Windows is configured just fine. I've also created those file natively on linux and checked them in. Azure DevOps was the culprit. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried building the solution on

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu 20.04

and in both cases they came up fine. So I ruled out the possibility, that it was a misconfigured git installation on the development machine(s).

That left me only with our CI/CD pipeline as a possible offender. So I've created a `.gitattributes` file with the following content:

```
*.sh text eol=lf
```

which solved the issue. The files are now being checked out and copied correctly. No more errors during runtime.

As an alternative, there was always the possibility to create an initContainer on K8s to install dos2unix and fix the files there, but that felt way less elegant and more like using nukes for hunting rabbits.

Huge Thank you to BMitch for giving me the advise to check to files inside the container, not just on the source.